# HTML spellcheck on existing text Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use HTML spellcheck on a textarea in Chrome. This works on the text I type but, I need to use it with existing text. This doesn't work, only when I select the text then the spellcheck activates. I simply use this:

```
<TEXTAREA spellcheck="true" class="operatorchat" name="inputtext" id="inputtext">This text is worng!</TEXTAREA>
```

In Firefox it works. Is there any code to make it work, I thought about selecting and deselecting with Javascript but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just throwing this out there- it may not be possible. When they made Chrome the good ol' boys at Google took a lot of shortcuts and used a lot of tricky code to make the end program take up less resources and run faster at the expense of functionality. I've found countless minor glitches in Chrome which would be **way** too resource heavy to fix, so they remain.

Comment: In the canary build selecting all text doesn't do anything. You have to select the individual word to trigger spellcheck for that word. Removing the text and adding it after a delay also doesn't work. So I guess you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this one and works great!

http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

Comment: jQuery is great and does all things

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Ben Do you have an up-to-date link for this?

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 spec allows browsers to decide if they want to start spell-checking by default or not.  FF 5 does; Chrome 12 doesn't.  So it actually is working.  Just, unfortunately, not the way you want.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-spellcheck